# Templated varying size structures in contiguous memory in C++

Tags: c++, templates, memory, memory-management, buffer

I am faced with the following problem. I want to make a templated function that can handle as many structures as possible, but it comes with the restriction that it needs to be able to copy all the data contiguously into a buffer.

So for example:

```
struct A{
    int foo;
    int bar;
}
```

Should become a buffer with 8 bytes.

```
struct B{
   int foo;
   vector<int> bar;
}

B.bar = vector<int>(2);
```

Should become a buffer with 12 bytes.

For the case of B, if I already know how B looks like, I can call malloc() to allocate the 12 bytes and manually copy the data into this buffer.

Is there a way to achieve this though templates, or do I need to add the restriction that any structure given to my templated function must already be stored contiguously?

Edit:

This is what I mean by copying the data of B to a buffer.

```
int *buffer = (int*) malloc(sizeof(int)+sizeof(int)*bar.size());

buffer[0] = foo;

for(int i=0; i<B.bar.size(), i++)
    buffer[i+1]=B.bar[i];
```

Comment: *I can call malloc() to allocate the 12 bytes and manually copy the data into this buffer.* -- And thus trash your `vector` object.

Comment: *Should become a buffer with 12 bytes* -- [See this](https://www.ideone.com/Iq2kLR).

Comment: What's the motivation for your function template? What are the use cases?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I don't see the relevance of your code. There are 3 ints assumed to be 4 bytes each, the final buffers size needs to be 12 bytes. What you have is the size of the struct, which will always be 32 bytes in this case, regardless of vector size, because the size fo vector is 24 bytes. and the size of int is 8 bytes in this case.

Your example has nothing to do with my question, std::vector stores metadata (inluding the pointer to the data) but it does not directly store the data. If I copy the actual data to a contiguous region in memory only the actual data would be copied

Comment: @RSahu I am writing a wrapper for OpenGL ssbos, and thus I require to pass the data to the GPU as a contiguous packet. The use case for this function is to be able to generally compact the data and pass it to the GPU

Comment: @Makogan Then you need to put a better explanation to what you're posting.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I feel you jumped to conclusions too quickly. My explanation is clear, or so it seems to me. I need to take the data in the structure and copy it to a contiguous buffer. And my examples clearly reflect that I want to copy the data only, not the metadata.

Comment: You cannot allocate a `std::vector` using `malloc`. That is your first problem. The second is that `sizeof(B)` is a compile time constant, which doesn't depend on the number of elements in `bar`. A third, and bigger, problem is that `std::vector` is **not** storing its members inside `B`, but on the heap, so its is non-contiguous.

Comment: @Makogan -- *I can call malloc() to allocate the 12 bytes and manually copy the data into this buffer.* -- Give an example (a more complete one) of this code you say is possible with the `struct B` and `malloc`.  That is where the confusion (to me) starts.

Comment: @BoPersson I know all of thse, hence why I said that I could call malloc (I, the user can allocate the memory) and manually copy the data to the buffer (thus guaranteeing the data to be compact). I never said I was going to allocate the vector memory with malloc (although you can actually do that if you know what you are doing). I am aware of all of these issues, hence why I know I need to copy the data to a buffer, I am asking if there is a way to to this generically.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I understand, I have made an edit, please let me know if this is clearer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the post, you said,

> I want to make a templated function that can handle as many structures as possible

In a comment you said,

> I am writing a wrapper for OpenGL SSBOs, and thus I require to pass the data to the GPU as a contiguous packet. The use case for this function is to be able to generally compact the data and pass it to the GPU

The objective makes sense. The strategy to get there, using a function template, is possibly not the right one.

Use of overloaded functions is probably your best option.

```
using BufferData = std::vector<char>;

BufferData toBufferData(A const& a);
BufferData toBufferData(B const& b);
```

Comment: This strategy however, requires to have an overloaded function per each new structure that you want to handle, something I'd like to avoid if possible.

Comment: @Makogan, That's a lofty goal but I don't think you can accomplish that with anything beyond simple POD-types. Even `struct`s that have a padding for alignment will be a problem.

Comment: Is there a way to make a templated function that forces its members to implement an interface like in java?

Comment: @Makogan, of course. `void template <typename T> foo(T const& t) { t.bar(); }` will work only if `T` has a member function `bar()`.

Comment: I assume that would be a compile time check, correct?